# How to create Payflow link sandbox account

Tags: paypal, payflowlink

I need to create payflow link module for website and I need test account.

I do not want to buy Payflow link, but I want to create something like Sandbox offers.

Is there any solutions to get it?

Not just paypal sandbox account, but Payflow link, with Partner, Merchant login and other details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paypal is retiring Payflow link in favor of Website Payments Standard and Pro. I had to sign up for a Website Payments account and then send a support ticket to change it back to Payflow. In my support ticket I explained that I already had an app using Payflow and needed to be able to test it still. They will give you a spiel about how everyone will have to upgrade soon, but if you insist that you have to test with the current technology (Payflow) then you'll get your account changed.

Comment: is Payflow has notification mechanism like IPN?

Comment: With Payflow link, you can enter in a URL to send notification back to.

Comment: I mean payflow pro, I am using payflow pro java sdk to implement payment solution. but initially I had started with paypal pro and used IPN notification handler.. but Now have to move to payflow pro using sdk apis..

so my doubt is, Is notification mechanism available in payflow pro sdk..?

Comment: You should create a new question with more details